# IE - Can’t connect securely to this page

Tags: security, internet-explorer, ssl, tls

I'm a developer wanting to get to a site on a LAN with a self-signed certificate. I want to bypass the warning and go to the site.

I have the following IE error message:

> Can’t connect securely to this page
>
> This might be because the site uses outdated or unsafe TLS security settings. If this keeps happening, try contacting the website’s owner.
>
> Try this:
> •Go back to the last page

I have looked in Internet Explorer security settings, set to in LAN zone and lowest security settings. All my TLS versions were already enabled. SSL was disabled, but enabling it made no difference. I restarted IE when I changed the settings.

Any ideas?

Comment: What TLS versions does your Internet Explorer support, and what TLS versions does the server support? It seems there is a mismatch. When a protocol can't be agreed upon, this can happen. Also, what OS and what version of IE?

Comment: What version of IE?

Comment: IE11. In IE it has TLS1 / 1.1 / 1.2 all available and selected. Certificate is from 2018. I am not sure how I can tell what the server supports as I don't have direct access to the machine, I can ask though. Tried on 2 PCs.

Comment: Does Edge work? As IE is now completely out of support & the functionality has been moved to Edge, that's really all you should be bothered about.